# Apache htaccess rewrite rule regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having difficulty getting a rewrite rule to work.

Directories look like

```
http://localhost/javascript/4184/widgets/jquery.quickDialog.js
```

and I want them to look like

```
http://localhost/javascript/widgets/jquery.quickDialog.js
```

This is the regex I am using

```
   RewriteRule ^javascript/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-./]+).js javascript/$2.js
```

My entire .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#REWRITE RULES
#---------------------

#RULE JAVASCRIPT VERSIONING PATH 

RewriteRule ^javascript/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-./]+).js javascript/$2.js [R]

#RULE JSMIN VERSIONING PATH 
RewriteRule ^js_min/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-./]+).js js_min/$2.js [R]


#RULE BLOCK MXUNIT FROM PUBLIC 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost
RewriteRule ^mxunit/.*  [L]

#RULE CSS VERSIONING PATH 

RewriteRule ^css/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-./]+).css css/$2.css [R]

</IfModule>
```

and relevant apache2.conf parts

```
<Directory /home/{username}/wwwroot>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
</Directory>


<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/home/{username}/wwwroot"
        ServerName localhost
        LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
        <Directory />
                Order allow,deny
                AllowOverride all
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yeah, the actual file structure is /javascript/widgets/jquery.quickDialog.js

We use the 4 digit code for cache busting, which is why I want the rewrite.

Comment: It does generate a 500 if I put in garble.  I also have logging enabled and I can see that some of the rules hit, like 
    RewriteRule ^css/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-./]+).css css/$2.css [R]

Comment: I just noticed something strange. I edited the request in chrome developer tools and manually deleted the 4 digit directory, but the request STILL came up 404. I can see that the file exists in the directory as the uri states, but 404 none the less. Am I missing some apache thing?

Comment: ok `http://localhost/javascript/widgets/jquery.quickDialog.js` giving 404 is the main problem that you have to figure out